# Take samples from normal distribution N(20,3), find $P\left\{\left|\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i-\frac{1}{15}\sum_{j=1}^{15}y_j\right|\gt0.3\right\}$

Tags: probability

Take two independent samples of capacity 10 and 15 from normal distribution $N(20, 3)$, find the probability that the absolute value of the two samples' mean difference is greater than 0.3.

I think the equation is: $$P\left\{\left|\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i-\frac{1}{15}\sum_{j=1}^{15}y_j\right|\gt0.3\right\}$$
I don't know what's the core of solving this problem (or what knowledge is involved). By the way, the answer is 0.6744.

Comment: hint: sum of normals is normal.

Answer (score 1):

First,

$$P\left(\left|X\right| > a\right) = P\left(X > a\right) + P\left(X < -a\right).$$

Here $X$ is the difference of the two sample averages. Each sample average is normally distributed (with what mean and variance?), and their difference is normally distributed as well (again, with what mean and variance)? Once you have the correct parameters of the distribution of $X$, you can do the above calculation.

Comment: Yes, I got it. xi~N(20, 0.3), yi~N(20, 0.2), their difference~N(0, 0.5). And the answer is there. Thanks